# Function returning Array[0] when array has elements | Typescript/Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I'm having some problems with a function on Typescript/Javascript where im expecting a function to return an array with X elements inside.

**The function should return:**

[image]

**Instead I get:**

[image: Sad Array]

So I can't use any array method such as map. I have no clue why when I log right after pushing an element, the array is in the expected format Array[X], but when I log before the resolve i get an Array[0]

**This is the function:**

```
public getUsers(object: any): Promise<Array<User>> {
let users: Array<User> = [];

return new Promise(resolve => {
  if (object) {
    object.map(userID => {
      this.getUserById(userID).then(user => {
        users.push(this.newResource(user));
        console.log('Right ->', users);
      });
    });
  }
  console.log('Wrong ->', users);
  resolve(users);
});
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are logging and `resolve`ing [before the asynchronous callback(s) runs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/1048572) and pushes values.
Also [you are confused by the `console`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4057440/1048572).

Since you are already using promises, the solution is easy:

```
public getUsers(object: any): Promise<Array<User>> {
  if (object) {
    var p = Promise.all(object.map((userID, i) => {
      return this.getUserById(userID).then(user => {
        console.log('got user '+i, user);
        return this.newResource(user);
      })
    })).then(users => {
      console.log('Right: all done', users);
      return users;
    });
    console.log('Wrong: too early');
    return p;
  } else {
    return Promise.resolve([]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Bergi for not only posting the right answer, but also for the explanation with the links.